# Webservice deployed in Linux(Jboss) cannot bbe Accessed from WebLogic12C in Wndows

Tags: java, linux, weblogic12c

We have a PDF webservice deployed in Linux Machine running on Jboss. We have WebLogic application servers running on Linux and Windows 10 machines. Application Deployed in Linux (on WebLogic) runs without any issues accessing the WebService on Linux (on Jboss). But the Same application Deployed in Windows 10 cannot access the WebSerice in Linux Machine. 
       
I am getting a:
**javax.xml.ws.WebServiceException: java.io.IOException: An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host>** 
when the web service is called from the Windows Application.

****PLEASE NOTE: THERE IS NOTHING WRONG IN THE WE SERVICE -AS I HAVE SAID, IT WORKS GREAT AS LONG AS BOTH THE WEBSERVICE AND THE APPLICATION ARE DEPLOYED IN LINUX MACHINES.**

THERE IS A ABRUPT SOCKET CLOSURE SOMEWHERE. I HAVE TRACED UPTO THE WLSProvider.class. But cannot figure out what the course it.

Why this could happenbetween Windows/Linux?
I also have checked Identity, HandShake and Trustscerts are all OK.

Exception Trace (partial) below.....

```
javax.xml.ws.WebServiceException: java.io.IOException: An existing connection was forcibly
closed by the remote host>
<Dec 18, 2020 6:59:49,265 AM CST> <Notice> <StdErr> <BEA-000000> at weblogic.wsee.jaxws.spi.WLSProvider > .createServiceDelegate(WLSProvider.java:195)
<Dec 18, 2020 6:59:49,265 AM CST> <Notice> <StdErr> <BEA-000000> at weblogic.wsee.jaxws.spi.WLSProvider > .createServiceDelegate(WLSProvider.java:150)>
<Dec 18, 2020 6:59:49,265 AM CST> <Notice> <StdErr> <BEA-000000> <at javax.xml.ws.Service.<init>(Service.java:77)>
<Dec 18, 2020 6:59:49,265 AM CST> <Notice> <StdErr> <BEA-000000> <at webservices.pdf.client.PdfCreator.<init>(PdfCreator.java:59)>
<Dec 18, 2020 6:59:49,265 AM CST> <Notice> <StdErr> <BEA-000000> <at 
reports.showPdf(reportController.java:1534)>
```

```
This is the Webservices PDF service definition
=========================== WEB SERVICE ON LINUX ========================== 
        import java.net.MalformedURLException;
        import java.net.URL;
        import javax.xml.namespace.QName;
        import javax.xml.ws.WebEndpoint;
        import javax.xml.ws.WebServiceClient;
        import javax.xml.ws.WebServiceFeature;
        import javax.xml.ws.Service;
        
         
        @WebServiceClient(name = "PdfCreator", 
                          wsdlLocation = "htpps://blah.blah/forms?wsdl",
                          targetNamespace = "urn:weblogicws.webservices.pdf:pdfservice:1.0") 
        public class PdfCreator extends Service {
        
            public final static URL WSDL_LOCATION;
        
            public final static QName SERVICE = new QName
              ("urn:weblogicws.webservices.pdf:pdfservice:1.0", "PdfCreator");
            public final static QName PdfCreatorPort = new 
                QName("urn:weblogicws.webservices.pdf:pdfservice:1.0", "PdfCreatorPort");
            static {
                URL url = null;
                try {
                    url = new URL("htpps://blah.blah/forms?wsdl");
                } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
                    java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(PdfCreator.class.getName())
                        .log(java.util.logging.Level.INFO, "Error");
                }
                WSDL_LOCATION = url;
            }
        
            public PdfCreator(URL wsdlLocation) {
                super(wsdlLocation, SERVICE);
                
            }
        
            public PdfCreator(URL wsdlLocation, QName serviceName) {
                super(wsdlLocation, serviceName);
            }
        
            public PdfCreator() {
                super(WSDL_LOCATION, SERVICE);
            }
            
             
            public PdfCreator(WebServiceFeature ... features) {
                super(WSDL_LOCATION, SERVICE, features);
            }
        
             
            public PdfCreator(URL wsdlLocation, WebServiceFeature ... features) {
                super(wsdlLocation, SERVICE, features);
            }
        
            
            public PdfCreator(URL wsdlLocation, QName serviceName, WebServiceFeature ... features) {
                super(wsdlLocation, serviceName, features);
            }
         
            @WebEndpoint(name = "PdfCreatorPort")
            public PdfCreatorPortType getPdfCreatorPort() {
                return super.getPort(PdfCreatorPort, PdfCreatorPortType.class);
            }
         
            @WebEndpoint(name = "PdfCreatorPort")
            public PdfCreatorPortType getPdfCreatorPort(WebServiceFeature... features) {
                return super.getPort(PdfCreatorPort, PdfCreatorPortType.class, features);
            }
        
        }
```

```
    ==============================WEB Application Side =======================
            //This is the code block in the Application Side
            @WebServiceClient(name = "PdfCreator", 
                              wsdlLocation = "htpps://blah.blah/forms?wsdl",
                              targetNamespace = "urn:weblogicws.webservices.pdf:pdfservice:1.0") 
            public class PdfCreator extends Service {
            
                public final static URL WSDL_LOCATION;
            
                public final static QName SERVICE = new
                  QName("urn:weblogicws.webservices.pdf:pdfservice:1.0", "PdfCreator");
                public final static QName PdfCreatorPort = new
                  QName("urn:weblogicws.webservices.pdf:pdfservice:1.0", "PdfCreatorPort");
                static {
                    URL url = null;
                    try {
                        url = new URL("htpps://blah.blah/forms?wsdl");
                    } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
                        java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(PdfCreator.class.getName())
                            .log(java.util.logging.Level.INFO, "Error");
                    }
                    WSDL_LOCATION = url;
                }
            
                public PdfCreator(URL wsdlLocation) {
                    super(wsdlLocation, SERVICE);
                    
                }
            
                public PdfCreator(URL wsdlLocation, QName serviceName) {
                    super(wsdlLocation, serviceName);
                }
            
                public PdfCreator() {
                    super(WSDL_LOCATION, SERVICE);
                }
                
                 
                public PdfCreator(WebServiceFeature ... features) {
                    super(WSDL_LOCATION, SERVICE, features);
                }
            
                 
                public PdfCreator(URL wsdlLocation, WebServiceFeature ... features) {
                    super(wsdlLocation, SERVICE, features);
                }
            
                
                public PdfCreator(URL wsdlLocation, QName serviceName, WebServiceFeature ... features) {
                    super(wsdlLocation, serviceName, features);
                }
             
                @WebEndpoint(name = "PdfCreatorPort")
                public PdfCreatorPortType getPdfCreatorPort() {
                    return super.getPort(PdfCreatorPort, PdfCreatorPortType.class);
                }
             
                @WebEndpoint(name = "PdfCreatorPort")
                public PdfCreatorPortType getPdfCreatorPort(WebServiceFeature... features) {
                    return super.getPort(PdfCreatorPort, PdfCreatorPortType.class, features);
                }
            
            }
```

This is the block where the PDF service is invoked. The line numbered 1534 is where
the PdfCreator object is instantiated. Right there is where error starts.
//reportController.java

```
public static void showPdf(OutputStream outResultStream, String rptname, 
     String servicesWsdlLocation ) {
     try {
         
                PdfCreator pdfService = null;
                 
                if (servicesWsdlLocation != null) {
Line:1534                  pdfService = new PdfCreator(new URL(servicesWsdlLocation ));
                     
                } else {
                    logger.info("showPdf:servicesWsdlLocation IS NULL");
                }
     } catch (Exception e) {
                
                e.printStackTrace();
                
                logger.error("Exception in showPdf -> " + e.getMessage());
            }
    
}
```

Comment: Are you using JBoss EAP 6.4 ? Also, do you have any idea about the size of the request? Is it larger than 2MB?

Comment: Also, search for a firewall rule which blocks the request.

Comment: Yes the webservice is deployed in jboss 6.4 where as the Web Application is running on WebLogic 12c

Comment: Size of the request is very small. Not near of 2MB at all.